# Exclude a string from a query

Tags: regex

Currently, I am using the following regex to filter URLs:

```
2014/^[0-9]+$
```

However, I need to modify this to be able to accomidate things like this:

```
2014/54648/aslug
```

I want to exclude the `aslug` part from the match, so I only get `2014/54648` as a match, but I do not know how to do this.

The results of the `2014/^[0-9]+$` query

```
2014/51643/mary   < exclude from the results
2014/36544/       
2014/46454/mike   < exclude from the results
2014/51643/julie  < exclude from the results
```

Comment: What do you mean "exclude" it from the match?  You want it to match the url and then remove the 'aslug' part from the url?  Or you want it to match but only capture the '2014/54648' part and not capture '/aslug'? Or if the url has '/aslug', the regex simply does not match and will only match '2014/[0-9]+'?  Your question is unclear.

Comment: Yes, "the regex should only match '2014/[0-9]+' " strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^2014/[0-9]+
```

Just removing the `$` should be enough.

`2014/51643/mary` isn't matching because `^2014/[0-9]+$` requires that the last character should be a digit. So `^2014/[0-9]+` should be enough because it will match '2014/' then all subsequent characters until they are a digit.

Also the `^[0-9]` should be only `[0-9]`. `^` should be used only to represent the start of string or be a group negation (eg /[^xyz]*/g will match every character of a string that are **not** the letters x, y or z)

Comment: shouldn't it be `/2014/^[0-9]+$/^(?:/\w*)?$/`

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you ?

```
(2014\/[0-9]+)\/\w+
```

The \w is "any word character" which includes underscores, and the parentheses mark the enclosed section as a result you can reference in the matches as "\1" or some such depending on the library you are using.